# Saving files received through DatagramPackets in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to send Files in fragments using DatagramPackets in Java (part of an assignemt.) When I am trying to save the incoming File I get access denied error, but I believe that it is not a permissions issue.
Here is the brunt of it:

I let the user sending the file to choose it using FileChooser. And create a new Message object.

```
//....
File f = content.showFileChooser();
            byte type = Byte.parseByte("4");
            Message m;
            try {
                if (mode == 1){
                    m = new Message(f, content.getServerData().getFragmentSize(), (short) (sentMessages.size()+1), type);
                    serverThread.send(m);
                }
//...
```

During Message creation the file gets split up into byte arrays, where the size of each array is predetermined by the user. The code is quite lengthy so I am not going to post the chopping process, but this is how I convert the File object into a big byte[] which then gets chopped up

```
    Path p = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
    this.rawData = Files.readAllBytes(p);
```

After the Message is created and chopped up into byte arrays I send them using DatagramPackets. The other side then uses those to create a new Message object. Once all fragments arrive rawData is extracted from the Message object again. The problem believe lies here:

```
            Message m = receivedMessages.get(msgIndex-1);
            byte[] fileData = m.getFile();
            if (fileData != null){
                System.out.println("All file fragments received.");
                content.append("Received a file in" + m.getFragmentCount()+" fragments. Choose directory. " ,1);
                //I BELIEVE THIS TO BE THE CRITICAL POINT
                String filePath = content.chooseDirectory();
                if (filePath == null)
                    return;
                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                    fos.write(fileData);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Once all fragments arrive I let the user select a directory using FileChooser with DIRECTORY_ONLY choice mode. As I understand, FileOutputStream requires a full path for the new File. Do I have to send the file name and extension separately or can it be extracted from the received File data?

Comment: `FuleOutputStream` does not require a full path. See the Javadoc. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing directory path to `filePath`, then try to open *that directory* with `FileOutputStream`. No wonder that doesn't work, you have to specify the filename too.

```
String filename = "myfile.txt"; //Or receive and set this some other way
File outFile = new File(filePath, filename);
fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
```

I don't see you sending/receiving the filename anywhere, though. You'll need to either make it constant or transfer it along with file contents.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I have resolved the issue by sending a seperate message containing the file name and extension.